# equal function for a calculator

Tags: jquery, function, calculator

I am building a calculator. I make numbers, clear and operators functions worked but I could not figured it out how to make an equal function work for a calculator. I want to pass all add(), multiply(), divide(), and subtract() functions to an equal function.

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var add = function(a, b) {
    a = parseInt(a);
    b = parseInt(b);
    return a + b;
  }

  var subtract = function(a, b) {
    return a - b;
  }

  var multiply = function(a, b) {
    return a * b;
  }

  var divide = function(a, b) {
    return a / b;
  }

  var userInput = []; //initial user input
  var arrNum = []; //will hold push parsed input
  var operation = "";

  $('.number').click(function() {
    var v = $(this).val();
    $('.screen').val($('.screen').val() + v);

  });

  $('.operator').click(function() {
    operation = $(this).val();
    var v = $(this).val();
    $('.screen').val($('.screen').val() + v);
  });

  $('.clear').click(function() {
    $('.screen').val('');
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="screen" id="display" readonly />
<br>
<br>
<button href="#" type="button" class="number" value="1">1</button>
<button href="#" type="button" class="number" value="2">2</button>
<button href="#" type="button" class="number" value="3">3</button>
<button href="#" type="button" class="operator add" value="+">+</button>

<br>
<button href="#" type="button" class="number" value="4">4</button>
<button href="#" type="button" class="number" value="5">5</button>
<button href="#" type="button" class="number" value="6">6</button>
<button href="#" type="button" class="operator multi" value="x">x</button>

<br>
<button href="#" type="button" class="number" value="7">7</button>
<button href="#" type="button" class="number" value="8">8</button>
<button href="#" type="button" class="number" value="9">9</button>
<button href="#" type="button" class="operator minus" value="-">-</button>

<br>

<button href="#" type="button" class="number" value="0">0</button>
<button href="#" type="button" class="clear" value="C">C</button>
<button type="button" class="equal" value="=">=</button>
<button href="#" type="button" class="operator divide" value="/">/</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Parse the input to split it up into two numbers separated by an operator. Then use an object that maps the operator to a function to call.

When the regexp matches, we can use the capture groups to get the operator and the two parameters. Then we can look up the corresponding function in the object, and call it with those parameters.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var add = function(a, b) {
    a = parseInt(a);
    b = parseInt(b);
    return a + b;
  }

  var subtract = function(a, b) {
    return a - b;
  }

  var multiply = function(a, b) {
    return a * b;
  }

  var divide = function(a, b) {
    return a / b;
  }
  
  var ops = {
    '+': add,
    '-': subtract,
    'x': multiply,
    '/': divide
  };

  var userInput = []; //initial user input
  var arrNum = []; //will hold push parsed input
  var operation = "";

  $('.equal').click(function() {
    var input = $('.screen').val();
    var parts = input.match(/^(\d+)(\D)(\d+)/);
    if (parts) {
      var op = parts[2];
      var func = ops[op];
      var param1 = parts[1];
      var param2 = parts[3];
      var result = func(param1, param2);
      $('.screen').val(Math.round(result));
    }
  });

  $('.number').click(function() {
    var v = $(this).val();
    $('.screen').val($('.screen').val() + v);

  });

  $('.operator').click(function() {
    operation = $(this).val();
    var v = $(this).val();
    $('.screen').val($('.screen').val() + v);
  });

  $('.clear').click(function() {
    $('.screen').val('');
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="screen" id="display" readonly />
<br>
<br>
<button href="#" type="button" class="number" value="1">1</button>
<button href="#" type="button" class="number" value="2">2</button>
<button href="#" type="button" class="number" value="3">3</button>
<button href="#" type="button" class="operator add" value="+">+</button>

<br>
<button href="#" type="button" class="number" value="4">4</button>
<button href="#" type="button" class="number" value="5">5</button>
<button href="#" type="button" class="number" value="6">6</button>
<button href="#" type="button" class="operator multi" value="x">x</button>

<br>
<button href="#" type="button" class="number" value="7">7</button>
<button href="#" type="button" class="number" value="8">8</button>
<button href="#" type="button" class="number" value="9">9</button>
<button href="#" type="button" class="operator minus" value="-">-</button>

<br>

<button href="#" type="button" class="number" value="0">0</button>
<button href="#" type="button" class="clear" value="C">C</button>
<button type="button" class="equal" value="=">=</button>
<button href="#" type="button" class="operator divide" value="/">/</button>
```

Comment: What is `input.match(/^(\d+)(\D)(\d+)/)` and `ops[parts[2]](parts[1], parts[3])` mean?

Comment: Have you done any research on how to use regular expressions in Javascript?

Comment: I did and I understand it but not this part `ops[parts[2]](parts[1], parts[3])`

Comment: I've updated the code to split that line into multiple statements, I hope it's more understandable now. I also added some more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `eval` method to evaluate the values passed
[Here is a link to the eval docs on mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)

Answer (score 0):

First, change the multiply symbol from `x` to `*`, and then use eval:

```
$('.equal').click(function() {
    alert(eval($('.screen').val()));
});
```